# Best way to manage a Configuration File?

Tags: java, configuration, config, configuration-files

A colleague and I were discussing best practices for managing a Configuration file, and we wanted to get some further feedback from others.

Our goal is for the configuration-file to specify what action should be taken, when certain events occur.

The 2 options that we are debating:

1. In the config-file, specify the class-path of the class, which implements the action to be taken *(eg: "ActionToTake" : "com.company.publish.SendEveryoneAnEmailClass")*. 
   Inside the code, when this event is encountered, we can then do *Class.forName(config.ActionToTake).newInstance().run()* in order to invoke the specified action.
2. In the config-file, specify in a human-readable-phrase, the action that should be taken *(eg: "ActionToTake" : "SendEveryoneAnEmail")*. Inside the code, when this event is encountered, we can then parse config.ActionToTake, and perform a mapping that translates this to action implementation *(eg: new SendEveryoneAnEmailClass().run())*

We are currently a very small team, and the only people reading/using this config file currently, is our team of software devs. But it's unclear if this will continue to be true in future.

Reasoning behind option 1: Anyone reading the config file will explicitly and immediately know what class will get invoked, and where it's implemented. This also allows for the action-class to be implemented/imported from a completely separate JAR file, without recompiling/changing our code.

Reasoning behind option 2: The config file should be a high level description of user-intent, and should not contain implementation details such as specific class names & package paths. Refactoring of class/package names can also be done without having to make config file changes.

Thoughts on which of these 2 design philosophies is preferred for configuration files?

Comment: Another and for me the most important advantage of option (1) is that later you can configure the ActionToTake to be a class you haven't even written yet, (or someone else can configure it with their own class), all without any changes to the code that calls run on the action.  This is much like how Spring configuration files work for IOC, and IDE's like Eclipse will optionally include XML configuration files when refactoring class and package names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1st option's advantage is, as jas noticed, the ability to 'link' code in the future. It's a real advantage only if you sell/distribute your software as a closed sourced package or if you plan to hot-swap behavior on production. You've already pointed out the cons - refactoring

2nd option:

- It won't help you with refactoring. If you change your action from SendEmail to BringBeer but you leave the string `send email` then you failed.
- Readability. `send-everyone-an-email` is as good as `SendEveryoneAnEmail`. Every developer will know what will happen. It can't be confused with `LaunchRockets`. Your code can find class based on some text, not necessarily the full qualified name. Your code can assume that Actions are in some specific package unless explicitly provided. And that is a way to combine both options.

Consider also another possibility: do the configuration in code. If you don't want to recompile the package, you can use scripting language (groovy). It lets you create very readable dsl, and you will have refactoring.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you clarify what you mean by the following: "it won't help you with refactoring. if you change your action from SendEmail to BringBeer but you leave the string send email then you failed."

The example I had in mind for the 2nd option, is that you have some sort of map/case statement, which will create an instance of SendEveryoneAnEmailClass when config.ActionToTake.equals("SendEveryoneAnEmail")

In this case, if you refactor the name of the class on an IDE, no further changes are needed. But in the 1st option, you'll have to manually edit the config file as well.

Comment: I think I understand your point now. You're referring to the case where we want to change the nature of the action itself (SendEmail vs BringBeer). By refactoring, I was referring to small changes like naming changes (SendEveryoneAnEmail vs SendEveryoneMail) or package path changes. 

For such formatting changes, if you use the 2nd option, IDEs can very easily do everything without any further work needed. But on the 1st option, some extra work is needed to change all the classpaths on the config file, which I believe to be a drawback of the 1st option.

Comment: @RvPr forgot to mention - you can add test that checks if all your config files contain valid data/existing classes